# Duda con decoradores en Python

Tags: python

Tengo una duda con la aplicación de decoradores.
Entiendo que un decorador es una función que recibe otra función como parámetro y la "envuelve". Pero si esta función tiene que devolver un valor (`return`) lo devuelve como `None`. Sin embargo, con `print` funciona sin problemas. 
No entiendo bien por qué func1 funciona sin problemas y func2 no:

```
# EJEMPLO BÁSICO DE DECORADOR 1

def decorador(func):
    def wraper(*args,**kwargs):
        print ("inicio de función")
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print ("Final de función")
    return wraper

@decorador
def func1(text):
    print (text)

@decorador
def funz2(text):
    return (text)

func1("función 1")
a = funz2("función 2")
print (a)
```

El resultado es:

```
inicio de función
función 1
Final de función
inicio de función
Final de función
None
```

Comment: te recomiendo este link http://www.3engine.net/wp/2015/02/decoradores-python/

Answer (score 0):

Una vez has decorado una función, cuando llamas a la función realmente estás llamando al decorador. Por tanto si quieres tener un valor retornado, debes hacer que lo retorne el decorador. Ya que lo que quieres retornar es lo que habría devuelto la función envuelta, captura ese resultado dentro del decorador para retornarlo al final.

Así:

```
def decorador(func):
    def wraper(*args,**kwargs):
        print ("inicio de función")
        resultado = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print ("Final de función")
        return resultado
    return wraper
```

Tu decorador también estaba funcionando sin problemas, sólo que al llegar al final sin un `return` explícito, se hacía un `return None` implícito.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. En este caso me funciona, pero no como quisiera, ya que el resultado de la función se muestra después de "Final de función" y no antes, que es lo que quisiera.  He leído el enlace que me ha pasado Tegito123 y tampoco me lo aclara.

Comment: @BigfooTsp Lo que pides, más que un decorador, sería un *Contexto de Ejecución*. Mírate los [controladores de contexto](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) (...y pregunta de nuevo si no lo ves claro).

Comment: @BigfooTsp Lo que pides es básicamente imposible. Fíjate que tienes `a = funcz2("Foo")`, lo cual ejecuta la función (decorada o no) y guarda el resultado en `a`. Y _después_ imprimes `a`. ¿Cómo va a salir el mensaje "Final de la función" después de eso? ¡La función (decorada o no) ya terminó de ejecutarse!

Comment: @BigfooTsp La única forma de poder mostrar el resultado de la funcion "envuelta" antes de que el decorador retorne, es que el propio decorador imprima ese resultado, por ejemplo antes del `print("Final de función")` puedes poner un `print(resultado)`. Naturalmente en ese caso ya no tiene sentido el `print(a)` del programa principal